# javafx native packaging msvcr100.dll

Tags: java, wix, inno-setup, javafx-8

I'm using netbeans 8, javafx 8 to package a native javafx application. Unless I add msvcr100.dll in front of the exe generated, an error is thrown saying msvcr100.dll is missing from your computer. The dll is already present in the jre folder in the dist bundle.

I'm using wix and Inno setup. How to overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: You need to *"add msvcr100.dll in front of the exe generated"* where ? How is this related to Inno Setup, or WiX ? Isn't the problem purely related to the installer generator ?

Comment: yes the problem is with the installer generator. The problem exists for "Image Only" packaging, which doesn't have the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak
You need to edit your .iss file in order to compile it into the exe.

```
[Files]
Source: "jfx-project\jfx-exe-file.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "jfx-project\resources\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

(You can also replace the '*' with 'msvcr100.dll')

That solved the problem for me :)

Hope it helps,
Laurenz

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your JDK, it was added some time ago ... got fixed in OracleJDK 1.8.0_40.

https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/74#issuecomment-55037760